# How do you compare values across tables in a Sequelize query

Tags: sequelize.js

How do I do this, its just the last line that I have trouble with ? Dialogues belong to Requests obviously.

```
SELECT * FROM Dialogues AS Dialogue,Requests AS Request
WHERE Dialogue.RequestId=Request.id
AND Dialogue.updatedAt < Request.updatedAt
```

I actually need to further restrict Request to only those who in turn have a Dialogue where universalId=VALUE AND Dialogue.executed > 0,
which I can do easy of course,

but how do I do the below ?, what goes after $gt: in place of "Dialogue.updatedAt" ?

```
myValue=something;
Dialogue.findAll({
  include : {
    model : Request,
    where:{updatedAt:{$gt:"Dialogue.updatedAt"}}
    include: {
      model:Dialogue,
      where:{
         PartyId:myValue,
         executed:{$gt:0}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as well -

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); 
const op = Sequelize.Op;

myValue=something;

Dialogue.findAll({
  include : {
    model : Request,
    where:{updatedAt:{$gt: {[op.col]: 'Dialogue.updatedAt'}}}
    include: {
      model:Dialogue,
      where:{
         PartyId:myValue,
         executed:{$gt:0}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and if you read the doco properly you will find the $col operator, so you just go

sourceField:{$col:'otherTable.otherfield'}